# Z-Index on sidebar help is incorrect

Tags: bug, design

When scrolling down the page to make a post on, it seems that the container holding "HOW TO FORMAT" has an incorrect z-index, or just looks invalid. It scrolls down and appears *below* the bottom image for the site *and* below the footer text, whereas on most sites it appears on top of all that stuff.

Take a look:

[image: screenshot-of-how-to-format]

This is on the latest version of Google Chrome for the desktop!